# Minimize Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

Can anyone please help me on how I can keep the angular material dialog minimized like below? I want to open multiple dialog's and able to switch between them. Is this possible in angular material (I was only be able to open stacked dialog's using material dialog component)?
[image]

Comment: There is no minimized dialog feature in Angular Material.

Comment: [Dialogs](https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html) are never used that way Material Design. They only open and close - and never hide or minimize. You are looking for a component that doesn't exist in Angular Material - the closest thing visually would be [snack bars](https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html), but they too are never used that way. You _might_ be able to hack a snack bar to do it - otherwise you are looking at creating your own custom component.

Comment: AngularJS or Angular? Google Fonts is built with AngularJS Material, but your question has the [tag:angular] tag.

Comment: @Edric its angular. i was inspired from the google fonts website and was having similar requirement. so checking if it was possible.

Comment: @Krishna You can try to use an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

Created a angular 2 material popup which can be minimized
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matminidialog

concept wise: 
1. it collects the needed elements of a popup in a containers array
 containers = [{ButtonLabel:"First", dialogId:0, animal: "cat"}];

2. On closing a dialog, uses this.dialogRef.close so an object of data can be returned back
3. A new id is added and given as dialogId (a new property)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start creating at least a bin on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).
Also it's usually not so much convenient to customize that much an existing and maintained official library. Instead I would suggest you to pass the data in another newly component they made, called [bottom-sheet](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview).

**Added/Edited:**

You can use the component to hold the minimization, then:

- eventually disable the close functionality.
- place it on the side or switch to an horizontal layout
- then you can add a modifier class on top of it

Example:

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container--horizontal .mat-nav-list { 
  display: flex
}

.mat-bottom-sheet-container--horizontal .mat-list-item {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 0 12px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
```

Obviously you need to implement also buttons to close/remove them.

Comment: i looked at that component it doesnt have minimize capability

Comment: The component itself is the minimization, then you have to build the communication between the 2.
If you prefer to switch to an horizontal layout, then you can add a modifier on top of it, like:

`.mat-bottom-sheet-container--horizontal .mat-nav-list { display: flex }`

Obviously you need to implement also buttons to close/remove them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. i will implement this and see.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the same thing, but nothing actually worked out. Ended up creating this library that does the same thing. [Min-Max-Popup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/min-max-popup)

Comment: is there a demo somewhere?